# Multiple images align issue in css

Tags: html, css

I am new to css and html. I made an application, and the pages in html and css. These are the images of my pages:

[image: Login page] and the second one is home page, that is user page

[image: home page]

This is my .css file code snippet:

```
body{  
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    background-image:url("../images/spring.png"), url("../images/security.png");
    background-size:200px 100px, 200px 100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position:top right, bottom right;
    margin-right:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    }
```

**Problem:** As you can see the images are not align same in the two pages, and I need the second image to be at the bottom of the page like the first one which is at top most of the page. Can any body guide me how to do it. I am sorry for the language as it is terrible. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont know how it works for you (two background image at same object), but you can use this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            img.first_image { position: absolute; top: 0px; }
            img.second_image { position: absolute; bottom: 0px; }
            body
            { background-color:#D8D8D8;
              background-size:200px 100px, 200px 100px;
              background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
              background-position:top right, bottom right;
              margin-right:200px;
              margin-left:15px;
              height:100%;
             }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="../images/spring.png" class="first_image" />
        <div>
             <!-- every things you need -->
        </div>
        <img src="../images/security.png" class="second_image" />
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `height:100%` to the `body` and `html`.

Comment: Please can you guide me more. I mean can you be more precise that how to add to html? I added in body but where to add in html? thanks

Answer (score 1):

try something like

```
body,html {height: 100%; width: 100%;}

#image-id {position: absolute; bottom: 0; right: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

it seems to be that the body isn't the full height of the page
try

```
body{  
    background-color:#D8D8D8;
    background-image:url("../images/spring.png"), url("../images/security.png");
    background-size:200px 100px, 200px 100px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat, no-repeat;
    background-position:top right, bottom right;
    margin-right:200px;
    margin-left:15px;
    height:100%;
}
```

That might be a little too much, though ... it might be worth setting it to `height:95%;` if it causes scroll-bars to appear

Answer (score 0):

Set both pictures to position fixed. Then the first one to top right and the second one to bottom right.
Then you have the pictures at every time in the wished position, even when the page content gets longer and is scrollable.

Comment: do u mean like this? `background-position:fixed, fixed;`