# CSS & HTML: Body background image alternative

Tags: html, css

I've a web page that is built the body tag in the CSS is currently set to:

```
body {
background: url(../images/bg_fence.png) bottom repeat-x;
}
```

URL: http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/careForAll/www/index.html

Right now, it shows a picture of a fence at the bottom of the page.

Instead of using a background in body to do this, how else can I do this?

Comment: Why? And why not simply add an image??

Comment: You still want it in the same place? You could have a div at the bottom of the page with 100% width and set the background in it?

Comment: I want to be able to set another background image in the body, but keep the fence at the bottom of the page.

Comment: @Dan675 I tried creating a div at the bottom with 100% width and set background, but it sat below the bottom of the house. I would still need it to be in the same place that it is.

Comment: Before I vote to close this, what's the problem in setting it as the body's background image?

Comment: You can add multiple background images with CSS.

Comment: I think you mean this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9484551/multiple-images-align-issue-in-css/9485682#9485682

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a div:

```
    <div class="fence"></div>
```

Then add the CSS:

```
    <style>
        div.fence {
            background: url(../images/bg_fence.png) repeat-x;
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            left: 0px;
            width: 100%;
            height: 17px;
        }
    </style>
```

Comment: hey thanks for your suggestion, I tried what you said but didn't seem to work. Please see http://s361608839.websitehome.co.uk/careForAll/www/index.html maybe something else to add? The Fence appears higher up the page when you scroll down.

Comment: Edited the code, try that.  That will make it float at the bottom of the browser even while scrolling.  You'll also want to adjust the height property to match the fence image height.

Comment: Ohhh, looks nearly there :) Take another look if you don't mind.. The fence div needs to sit behind the house, but be at the bottom of the page when you scroll to the bottom, not how it is now just being at the bottom of the page (if that makes sense).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `div` which spans the width of the entire page and comes last in your document flow. It would either have to be a `div` with `overflow: hidden` and a large image, or with a background image on the `div` instead of the `body`.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the `position:absolute` to `position:fixed` for `<div class="fence"></div>`.

Comment: On another note, visiting random websites is probably not a good idea, never know what kind of malware they've got there.